# getIntent() returning a null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-intent, null, maps

The method below returns a null pointer exception when the activity is opened.
Would anyone know why?
Is it something to do with no intent existing when getIntent() is called?

Any help would be appreciated.

Log:

```
04-21 15:38:03.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): Process: com.lyit.project, PID: 1910
04-21 15:38:03.237: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lyit.project/com.lyit.project.MapScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_screen);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)){
            doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){
            getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. How is your `Activity` being started? Under normal circumstances the ACTION should have something in it, unless you are launching the app with an explicit `Intent`. As @Drakkin suggests, you can/should check for ACTION == `null`, but I'm surprised that it is.

Answer (score 3):

Just check nullity of your intent and your action, default action is null.

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
  if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)){
    doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){
    getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, default ACTION should be `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
String action = intent.getAction();
 if (action != null && action.equals("registrationComplete")) {
}else {}
```